# How do you make this formula become continuous? [Approximation]

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have the recursive formula $u_{n-h}+2u_{n}+u_{n+h}$, how can I write it as a continuous formula?

I mean, for example, $u_{n-1}-2u_{n}+u_{n+1}\simeq \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial n^{2}}$

Note: $h=5$

Comment: One variant is to compare with trapezoidal integration, $\int_{n-h}^{n+h}f(x)dx=\frac{h}2(f(n-h)+2f(n)+f(n+h))+O(h^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Taylor

$$u_{n\pm h}=u\pm hu'+\frac{h^2}2u''\pm\frac{h^3}{3!}u'''+\cdots$$

and

$$u_{n-h}+2u_n+u_{n+h}\approx4u+h^2u''+\frac1{12}h^4u''''.$$

In principle, $h$ is neglectible and the approximation is just $4u$.

Comment: +1: But you should maybe inculde the O-Notation.

Comment: @MrYouMath: why should I, the OP didn't.